# C++ While loop terminating even though conditions are not met

Tags: c++, while-loop

I want the program to keep asking for values to do calculations until the flag is true then the program must stop, but it only ever executes once. I don't know if I am using the char the right way or if there is a better way to do these types of while loops with flags. Any help would be great.[enter image description here][1]

```
int main()
{
    displayMenu();
    bool flag = false;
    while(!flag)
    {
        int choice = 0; int val1 = 0; int val2 = 0; int ans = 0;
        cout << "Enter your choice (1-5): ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "\nEnter integer 1: ";
        cin >> val1;
        cout << "\nEnter integer 2: ";
        cin >> val2;
        if(choice < 0 || choice > 5)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter a choice between 1-5: ";
            cin >> choice;
        }
        if (choice == 1)
        {
          ans = Add(val1,val2);
          cout << "\nResult: " << ans << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {
          ans = Subtract(val1,val2);
          cout << "\nResult: " << ans << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 3)
        {
          ans = Multiply(val1,val2);
          cout << "\nResult: " << ans << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 4)
        {
          ans = Divide(val1,val2);
          cout << "\nResult: " << ans << endl;
        }
        if (choice == 5)
        {
          ans = Modulus(val1,val2);
          cout << "\nResult: " << ans << endl;
        }
        char c_flag[] = "n";
        cout << "Press Y or y to continue: ";
        cin >> c_flag;
        if(c_flag == "y" || c_flag == "Y")
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c_flag == "y"` -- C-style string comparison doesn't work this way. Use `std::string` or `strncmp` instead.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and possibly `-Wextra`. I believe GCC should warn you about what you are doing.

Comment: @jww regardless of whether the compiler warns about this *specifically*, enabling more warnings is always a good idea. +1.

Answer (score 5):

With data type `char c_flag[]`, condition `c_flag == "y"` will very likely never be met, because you are comparing two (different) *pointer* values, not their contents.

Use `std::string c_flag` instead, and at least your conditions should work as expected.

You could also write

```
char c_flag[] = "y";
...
if (strcmp(c_flag,"y")==0) ...
```

but I'd prefer the `std::string`-variant for following reason: with `char c_flag[] = "y"`, you allocate an array of size 2 (including string termination character); With `cin >> c_flag`, if you enter more than one character, you will exceed array length and yield undefined behaviour. With `std::string`, in contrast, the variable will "grow" if necessary.